# multipart encoded file content in perl

Tags: python, perl, rest, encoding, sandbox

I want to make a POST Request to a REST API service from Perl. As a POST Form parameter, the service expects a multipart encoded file.

```
use HTTP::Request::Common;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $file="/path/to/file";
my $REST_URL = "/path/to/REST/service";
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $response= $ua->post($REST_URL, ['file' => $file]);
```

I wrote the above code. But obviously the REST server could not understand the POST Request as I have only send the file path to the REST service instead of a multipart encoded file content. Could anyone please let me know how can I make a file multipart encoded and send it as POST Request to a REST service which expect a multipart encoded file as a Form Parameter?

As a side note, I actually want to write the equivalent Perl code of the Python code below.

```
REST_URL = "/path/to/REST/service"
SAMPLE_FILE = "/path/to/file"

with open(SAMPLE_FILE, "rb") as sample:
   multipart_file = {"file": ("temp_file_name", sample)}
   request = requests.post(REST_URL, files=multipart_file)
```

But, for my limited knowledge of Python, I didn't understand the line `multipart_file = {"file": ("temp_file_name", sample)}`. Explanation of what this line is exactly doing will help me as well, I think.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for [HTTP::Request::Common](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Request::Common)? It tells you exactly what you need to do, including the part where it says to specify a content type of `form-data` as a request header.

Comment: @MattJacob Thanks for the hint. After a second read, I understood it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in module documentation [`HTTP::Request::Common`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Request::Common)

```
$ua->post($REST_URL,
  Content_Type => 'form-data',
  Content      => [
    file => [$file]
  ],
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked with a little change. As the $file should be an array reference to be treated as file Part specification.

Comment: It worked after replacing $file scalar with an array reference. So I first declare an array and make the $file scalar the only element of that array. Then used the array_ref instead of $file in your above code. I now better understand the instruction "If one of the values in the $form_ref is an array reference, then it is treated as a file part specification" mentioned at [https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Request::Common]